# While creating selenium script for android browser, why this error showing?

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selendroid

[image: Why this error is showing?]
Why i am getting this error. which library file should i use to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the selenium-android-driver jar.  But the Android driver has been replaced by selendriod.  Instead you should do:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.android());
```